# Histogram plot using R/python with two variables[BC and Control] and their corresponding gene names

Tags: r, python, proteins, ggplot2

How do we plot histogram in R\Python with two variables[BC and Control] and their corresponding gene names examples is below:

[image]

Thank you,

Comment: That doesn't look like a histogram but a bar plot. To draw it with ggplot2 and `geom_col()`, check out this reference: [https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_bar.html](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_bar.html)

Comment: Yeah, I was just given an example through bar plot well, thanks @Cloudberry

Comment: How is a bar plot an example for a histogram? They're two different kinds of plots.

Answer (score 1):

Real data is better, particularly if genes names are wanted (complicated simulation) .... anyway there you go. Simulated values under a negative binomial which are pretty realistic to the data supplied (that'll be negative binomial, just not ranked).

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(2)
s1 = list(np.random.negative_binomial(1, 0.1, 500))
s2 = list(np.random.negative_binomial(1, 0.5, 500))
mydict = {'A':s1, 'B':s2}
df = pd.DataFrame(mydict)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

heights, bins = np.histogram(df['A'])
heights2, bins2 = np.histogram(df['B'], bins=bins)

width = (bins[1] - bins2[0])/3

ax.bar(bins[:-1], heights, width=width, facecolor='coral')
ax.bar(bins2[:-1]+width, heights2, width=width, facecolor='blue')
```

[image]

---

Here's horizontal bars (minor differences) with slightly different negative binomial values used ...

```
# same imports as before 

np.random.seed(2)
s1 = list(np.random.negative_binomial(1, 0.1, 500))
s2 = list(np.random.negative_binomial(1, 0.3, 500))
mydict = {'A':s1, 'B':s2}
df = pd.DataFrame(mydict)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

heights, bins = np.histogram(df['A'])
heights2, bins2 = np.histogram(df['B'], bins=bins)

width = (bins[1] - bins2[0])/3

ax.barh(bins[:-1], heights, width, facecolor='coral')
ax.barh(bins2[:-1]+width, heights2, width, facecolor='blue')
ax.invert_yaxis()
plt.show()
```

[image]

---

To adapt it you just need to provide an appropriate set of values that will then be fitted to a dataframe.